# How to debug PHP files in GWT Project

Tags: java, php, gwt

I am working in a gwt project in which it has hyperlinks referencing to PHP files. These php pages will generate input to other pages . The  execution flow switches between GWT and  PHP pages. I can't debug the end to end of the GWT code becoz of PHP files in between. Is there any way for debugging by using any third party tools .  BTW I am using Eclipse as IDE

Answer (score 0):

Hey Mate if you have not debugged as you codded (or you got put on to a project half done) you got a long night a head of you.

to my knowledge there is NO DECENT php debugs out there. Best way to debug PHP easy but hard

at start of PHP write

```
try {
```

then at the end of the file write

```
} catch (Exception $e) { var_dump $e; }
```

this will give you a out put of any errors on the page.
NOTE: if you have many errors you will have to keep trying the file and fixing it until it can parse through the whole script.